# ldap memberof overlay not working at all even with new entries

Tags: overlay, openldap, memberof

I've been trying 2 days not to get memberof overlay of openldap to work and give some actual results. 
My database config:

```
database    bdb
suffix      "dc=example,dc=net"
checkpoint  1024 15
rootdn      "cn=root,dc=exmple,dc=net"
rootpw          {SSHA}stuffffffff

directory   /var/lib/ldap

index objectClass                       eq,pres
index ou,cn,mail,surname,givenname      eq,pres,sub
index uidNumber,gidNumber,loginShell    eq,pres
index uid,memberUid                     eq,pres,sub
index nisMapName,nisMapEntry            eq,pres,sub

overlay memberof
```

Then

```
slaptest -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d/
```

Restart slapd and create test user and test group. 
Then ldap search to see the result:

```
[root@sso openldap]#  ldapsearch -W -H ldapi:/// "(uid=test123)" -b dc=example,dc=net memberOf
Enter LDAP Password: 
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=example,dc=net> with scope subtree
# filter: (uid=test123)
# requesting: memberOf 
#

# search result
search: 3
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 1
```

And still not showing the memberof attributes. According to the openldap documentation it should be exactly that simple - add overlay memberof to the slapd.conf and it should work. 
Any idea? 
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't state whether you added the new user to the new group, but in any case you've loaded the `memberof` overlay but not configured it. Unless you're relying on the default configuration, whatever that is, you need to confifure three or four aspects. See *man slapo-memberof* for details, I'm not going to repeat them here.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but maybe this will help somebody else. I am a noob that recently installed and used the memberOf overlay on an Openldap 2.4.31 (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) server. The most important things I learned were :

- Since OpenLDAP version 2.3, configuration is done dynamically ([OLC](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/slapd-config.html)) using Directory Information Trees, optionally making the static slapd.conf method obsolete. Use it.
- Add the memberof and refint overlays as [explained here](https://www.brianshowalter.com/blog/installing-configuring-openldap)
- EDIT: Keep in mind this overlay works with the (among others) `groupOfNames` `ObjectClass` and not work with the standard `posixGroup` `ObjectClass`.

Comment: The point about using `groupOfNames` did the trick for me - the overlay had been installed and groups (using `posixGroup`) had been created, but no users had the 'memberOf' attribute. Recreating the groups as 'groupOfNames' and then adding users to them worked.

Comment: Final point is false. It works with whatever object class you configure it to work with. I have been using it with `organizationalRole` and `groupOfUniqueNames` for nearly ten years.